# Ajax Call Syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Trying to do a simple ajax post, for some reason, it is not posting my data! It successfully posts to the file (ajaxpost.php) but no POST data is passed..

```
            var myKeyVals = {caption: "test"};
                $.ajax({ //Process the form using $.ajax()
                    type        : 'POST', //Method type
                    url         : 'ajaxpost.php', //Your form processing file url
                    data        : myKeyVals, //Forms name
                    dataType    : 'json',
                    success     : function(data) {

                    if (!data.success) { //If fails
                        if (data.errors.name) { //Returned if any error from process.php
                            $('.throw_error').fadeIn(1000).html(data.errors.name); //Throw relevant error
                        }
                    } else {
                            $('#success').fadeIn(1000).append('<p>' + data.posted + '</p>'); //If successful, than throw a success message
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Here is my AjaxPost.php..

```
        <?php
        $text = $_GET['caption'];
        $file = 'people.txt';
        // Open the file to get existing content
        $current = file_get_contents($file);
        // Append a new person to the file
        $current = "LOG: " . $text . "\n";
        // Write the contents back to the file
        file_put_contents($file, $current, FILE_APPEND);
        ?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using ```$_POST['caption']``` and not ```$_GET['caption']```?

Answer (score 1):

In your php file you're using `$_GET['caption']` but you should be using `$_POST['caption']` as this is a post request.

Answer (score 1):

`POST` data is accessed in PHP using `$_POST`, not `$_GET` !

Alternatively, if you wish to support both HTTP methods you can use `$_REQUEST`.